# How can I read .fds files in python?

Tags: python, file

I have received data in the form of **.fds** files which I have to analyze in python, but I do not know how to properly open these files and also how to read them properly in python. I'm beginner so I don't know if these files are widely used, although I did not find anything relevant and/or helpful in the internet.

So, the question is: how to properly open **.fds** files and how to read them in python?